# why this SCJP program gives output 21 but I am getting 20?

Tags: java, enums, scjp

```
public class Stepper 
{
enum Roman {I,V,X,L,C,M}
public static void main(String... args) 
{
    int x=7;
    int z=2;
    Roman r = Roman.X;
    do
    {
        switch(r)
        {
            case C : r = Roman.L;break;
            case X : r = Roman.C;
            case L : if(r.ordinal()>2) 
                        {
                            z += 5;//7,13,19
                        }
            case M : x++;//8,9,10
        }
        z++;//8,14,20
    }
    while (x<10);
    System.out.println(z); //
}
}
```

Comment: Hello all i am preparing for SCJP exams ... In the above program When manually done output of the program is 20 but through jvm its 21 ... correct me thank you in advance

Comment: See: http://www.coderanch.com/t/258402/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Enum

Comment: If there is a dfference between what you expect a program to do and what is does, the first thing you should try is to step through the code with your debugger. This will show you the values of all the variables after each line of code.

Answer (score 3):

When r = Roman.C,

```
case C : r = Roman.L;
break;
```

after case C executed the break, there's a z++ right after the break.

You missed that one.